# What is good HTML in-line CSS form?

Tags: html, css, formatting

I want to make bubbles containing content, placed around a HTML page. So, I made a .bubble CSS class, and put the positional values as an in-line style. This gave me some rather long lines.   The style guides of programming languages I've used dictate a maximum line length, and specify how overly long lines should be broken up. Something like

```
<div class="bubble"
    style="top: 10%;
    left: 40%;
    right: 60%;
    width: 480px;
    height: 295">
    Content.
</div>
```

...looks absurd. What is good form for this?

Comment: I would suggest having a class for each bubble, unless they are created in some kind of a loop, either server-side or client-side. It's hard to tell though, 'cause I don't know how many bubbles there are, and what their exact purpose is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rather look at that in one line. With that said, I pretty much never see it broken like that. And in some cases, I think the browser removes the line breaks anyways.

Though I would **really rather** not see in-line CSS.

However, if you have to have in-line CSS, I think the standard of 'whatever fits on the screen' which is 80 characters-ish still holds.

**EDIT**

Just to be sure, I did some light searching for in-line CSS guidelines and ever site I found is strongly against it as a practice all together. I know your question was about in-line CSS but I feel obligate to say **don't**. It breaks the concept of separation of concerns. It tightly couples your html to your CSS. What if you want to play around with a new design? Now you have to edit your html directly and risk breaking the flow or the page altogether instead of just pointing to a new CSS file.

If you need specific CSS for one particular element, slap an ID on it and throw it in your external CSS doc.

Comment: How does this work? As far as I understood CSS, it's supposed to be a modular description of what a page should look like, while the HTML itself gives shape and structure. How is this supposed to work? (this applies to all of the answers that point of the unelegence of this)

Comment: @Glycan You should put your css in an external css document, not inline with your HTML. In your example, you would use specific selectors to find the exact div you wanted to position directly. I'm not sure how much you know about CSS Selectors, but here is a list of them: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

You would probably keep the class="bubble" attribute and then use that as part of your selector. Let me know if that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** It's not necessary to have both *left* and *right* declarations. If you tell the browser that the element is 40% from the left, it will know that it's 60% from the right. That will save you a few characters of code, and will not change the outcome.

You didn't make a bubble css class. You made a bubble class **and** added inline css to the div tag. 
You have quite a few alternatives. I'm not quite sure why you haven't chosen them.

If line length is an issue, delete the spaces. You don't need them, and keeps the line shorter.

```
<div class="bubble" style="top:10%;left:40%;width;480px;height:295;">
Content.
</div>
```

But, agreeing with another post here, do not use inline css. It's bad practice. If the styles must be within the file (as in Tumblr themes) put them inside a style tag.

```
<style> .bubble {top:10%;left:40%;width:480px;height:295;}
</style>
```

Or do what most of us do, and put the style on a separate css file, with a link to it between the head tags.

```
 <link href="yourstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider doing this through js and jQuery? Alternatively, you could something like this:

```
$('.someBubble').css({
top: 10%;
    'left': '40%',
    'right': '60%',
    'width': '480px',
    'height': '295px'
});
```

Not knowing what constraints or limits you have to work with, this would at least let you keep styles from inlineing.